# How to get value of the ipaddress specified in TestKitchen using OHAI?

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen, ohai-gem

I am providing the `ipaddress` of the machine within my `kitchen.yml`:

```
  - name: node_abc
    driver:


      network:
      - ['private_network', {ip: '193.169.33.84'}]
```

When I try to retrieve the value of `ipaddress` using

```
ohai node[ipaddres]
```

I get `10.0.2.15` instead of `193.169.33.84`.

How can i get `193.169.33.84`?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
node["network"]["interfaces"]["eth1"]["addresses"].first.
```

The reason, why *ohai* picks the first interface (even if it's only a non-globally routed IP) is because the default route uses this interface. [This](https://github.com/chef/ohai/blob/1cb19d0609e3a9e8aa5abb34bd1125156cf9ed31/lib/ohai/plugins/linux/network.rb#L74-L76) should be the place in the code.